# List of ObservableCollection items in C#

Tags: c#, componentart

Don't know if my approach is correct, but I just want to understand this:

I have a ColorStopCollection of colors, this is a class from [Componentart](http://www.componentart.com) and this is the definition

```
    public sealed class ColorStopCollection : ObservableCollection<ColorStop>
    {
        public ColorStopCollection();
        public ColorStopMappingMode MappingMode { get; set; }
        public Palette Palette { get; set; }
        public ColorStopTransition Transition { get; set; }
        public Color GetColor(double value);
        public Color GetColor(double value, ColorStopTransition transition);
        public Color[] GetColorRange(int count);
        public Color[] GetColorRange(int count, ColorStopTransition transition);
        public Color[] GetColorRange(double minValue, double maxValue, int count, ColorStopTransition transition);
        protected override void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e);
        public GradientStopCollection ToGradientStopCollection();
        public GradientStopCollection ToGradientStopCollection(double minValue, double maxValue);
        public ColorStop[] ToSortedArray();
    }
```

So I made a Collection of colors, like this (the Green variable is a ColorStopCollection of a few shades of green

```
public static ColorStopCollection Green= new ColorStopCollection() 
    { new ColorStop{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF3F5D1C"), Offset=0},
      new ColorStop{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF4B7021"), Offset=20},
      new ColorStop{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF588227"), Offset=40},
      new ColorStop{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF658D37"), Offset=60},
      new ColorStop{Color=(Color)new ColorConverter().ConvertFrom("#FF85A562"), Offset=80}
    };
```

I have ten of these variables, I need to list them so I made this statement:

```
public static List<ColorStopCollection> AllColors = new List<ColorStopCollection>(){
        Green,
        Blue,
        Purple,
        Lilac,
        Orange,
        ...
    };
```

My problem is when I try to get an ColorStopCollection item of my List AllColors

```
Name                        Value   Type
GlobalColors.AllColors[0]   null    ComponentArt.Win.DataVisualization.Gauges.ColorStopCollection
```

I was hoping to get a ColorStopCollection element (The collection of green in this case) but I get null, am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you initialized `AllColors` before `Green`, so `Green` was null when you passed it.

Move each field initializer after the fields that it references.